# PHP not printing correctly after 17.04 -> 17.10 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, php

I was forced to upgrade Lubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 on my web server (Apache2) when 17.04 went end of life.
It seemed to go OK.
But now I see problems on PHP webpages:

```
<?php
include("./functions.php");
if(!isset($_COOKIE['Palloy-blogging'])) { 
       print "You are not logged in"; 
       exit; 
}
user = $_COOKIE['Palloy-blogging'];
if($user == "") { 
       print "You are not logged in !"; 
       exit; 
}
display_user($user);
?>
<HTML>
```

prints:

```
"; exit; } $user = $_COOKIE['Palloy-blogging']; if($user == "") { print "You are not logged in !
```

I can see from other similar bugs that PHP has been upgraded to 7.1, but I don't see how that could give this result.

'sudo apt update' => no updates available

Answer (score 0):

Examining /etc/apache2/mods-available/ there are files:
php7.0.conf, php7.0.load, php7.1.conf and php7.1.load .

Examining /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ :
there is no php*

So $ sudo a2enmod php7.1.conf gives:
Error: module php7.1.conf does not exist!
[Why ???]

$ sudo a2enmod php7.1.load gives:
Enabling module php7.1
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
systemctl restart apache2

$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
$

And it works!
I would be interested to know exactly why.